# We cannot stop activity Broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Hi I have a problem to register broadcast receiver I dont know why
This is my code

Main Activity

```
public class Service extends Activity {
private MyServiceReceiver myReceiver;
TextView txtManual;
TextView txtAuto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_service);



    IntentFilter filter;
    filter = new IntentFilter(MyService.NEW_DATA);
    myReceiver = new MyServiceReceiver();
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);


txtAuto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAuto);
txtManual = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtManual);

Button cmdStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmdStart);

cmdStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        startService(new Intent(Service.this, MyService.class));
    }
});

Button cmdRefresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cmdRefresh);

}

public class MyServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    txtAuto.setText(intent.getStringExtra("data")); 
    if(intent.getStringExtra("data")== null){

        txtManual.setText("Null");

    }
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override


protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);

    super.onStop();
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    IntentFilter filter;
    filter = new IntentFilter(MyService.NEW_DATA);
    myReceiver = new MyServiceReceiver();
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);

    super.onResume();
}}
```

This is my manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.t8ej1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <service android:name="MyService"/>



    <activity
        android:name="com.example.t8ej1.Service"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
And this is my logcat




 07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop       activity    
 {com.example.t8ej1/com.example.t8ej1.Service}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not    registered: com.example.t8ej1.Service$MyServiceReceiver@40d10a30
 07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):    at       android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
 07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469)
  07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:141)
  07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
 07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):     at    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
```

07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:   Receiver not registered: com.example.t8ej1.Service$MyServiceReceiver@40d10a30
    07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:657)
    07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1339)
    07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):     at   android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:445)
     07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):    at com.example.t8ej1.Service.onStop(Service.java:85)
     07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1205)
     07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5246)
    07-08 01:44:26.328: E/AndroidRuntime(6315):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3410)

I registered the broadcast receiver in `OnCreate` and `OnResume` method and unregistered in `OnPause` and `OnStop` Method but when I quit the application it generate an error!!

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you already unregistered it in onPause method. If you see the activity life cycle, you can see that onPause is called before onStop. How about unregistering it only once in the onPause method and see if there is BroadcastReceiver leakage?

Another thing, I've noticed is that you are registering the same receiver again in onResume method, is that what you really want? See the life cycle diagram, that will definitely be handy to you. :)

Comment: Yes you are right!!!I eliminated the code in OnResume and onPause method!!Thank!!

Comment: So accept the answer :) And mind the case when the app has been resumed, you might have to register the receiver again, I suggest to take the registering code to onResume() and have it remove from onCreate(). Just follow the life cycle diagram and you should not be having problems in future. :) Cheers.